# Would questions about writing systems be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, status-completed, scope

Should this site cover only spoken language or also written language, including alphabets and other writing systems? Or should it allow the latter only to a certain degree that overlaps spoken language in some way?

Comment: Is "linguistics" a term that technically doesn't include writing systems?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In my humble opinion we should try to be as liberal as possible when it comes to which linguistics-related fields are on-topic, so I would say **on-topic**. Ha, if doesn't fit here, then where?

Comment: do you mean it's a no?

Comment: Ah. Uhm. Well. Yes.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that linguistics.SE is the place for discussion of writing systems, if only because no other exchanges are likely to cover this topic. Even if any of the other language SEs did cover writing systems appropriate to their subject, it's unlikely that they'd be willing to discuss comparison of writing systems. So, I vote yes.

Comment: I'm not sure this is sound reasoning. For any arbitrary topic X, it is possible that no exchange is likely to cover X, does that mean it should be covered here?

Comment: Of course that's not what I mean.

Answer (score 9):

I know you have already accepted but I vote yes as well. The written language has the same rights as the spoken one to appear here.

The point is that it must be from a Linguistics point of view, that's about the only "restriction" we could have. :)

Comment: To me, [this question about the names of letters](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/246/do-all-non-syllabic-non-logographic-scripts-have-pronounceable-names-for-their-l) seems to be beyond the scope of the science of linguistics, but I'm not 100% sure since I'm not a real linguist...

Comment: That question might be off topic because it's not exactly about Linguistics, asking the name of letters, but not because it's about written language per se.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't get that :D

Answer (score 2):

Too bad I'm late. A big YES from me.

Answer (score -1):

This is now a 7-year-old question, but what I think is that:

> Those questions should be off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics.