# Should we include Esperanto in our scope?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope

Before now, we have excluded conlangs from our scope, but Esperanto is on a whole different level. For example, it has [native speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Esperanto_speakers).

If Esperanto will be considered on topic, questions about it will still need to fit the other rules:

1. No usage/grammar questions if they're not focused on the Linguistics aspect;
2. No tips for learning the language;
3. It fits the point #7 in the FAQ that states:

   > *Questions about a single word/single language.* We decided to set such questions on topic, because they can bring up interesting facts, but with certain conditions. **(1)** The user provides evident research effort in their questions. This way we'd help you regardless of the difficulty of the question. :) **(2)** The question is more focused on the Linguistics aspect rather than the Usage one, because in that case it'd get off topic.
4. Any other rules in the SE sites or our FAQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### On topic

I vote for Esperanto to be included within the scope. Questions about this topic will need to be asked according to the rules of this site and the other SE sites.

Comment: I voted for this answer because in my knowledge Esperanto has greatly evolved over the past 100 years from a language project into a full-fledged language with native speakers and mass media. It has occupied its niche in linguistics by being an important subject in Interlinguistics and Esperantology. Besides, it is the only planned language which was recognized by UNIcert and is taught using the UNIcert's reference frame (A1-C2) in Germany and Polland.

Comment: I voted in favour. Esperanto has native speakers, and a substantial enough community of second-language speakers that it has been expanded to meet most human needs, and so is enough of a natural-type language that it comes within the realm of linguistics.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, and I want to add two things to it:

1. There is now an [Esperanto Stackexchange](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/) available
2. This does not make linguistical questions about Esperanto off-topic here

Comment: You linked to your account on Esperanto Stack Exchange. Why don't you just link to the main site page?

Comment: Cut-and-paste error. Corrected.

Answer (score -2):

### Off topic

I vote against this, because I think Esperanto should still be considered as outside of the scope and interest of our site.

Comment: I have voted for this answer.  Esperanto would become worthy of discussion here if it evolved from its original definition. So long as it doesn't do so, there's nothing to discuss.  But if it does start to evolve, it will become a very interesting study on language change.

Comment: @David Wallace: Have you had a chance to review the wiki for the "[modern evolution of Esperanto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_evolution_of_Esperanto)"?

Comment: @blunders - thanks for the link; that was really interesting.  I still don't think it's changed my mind though.  The article is about deliberate changes to the language; I'd be more interested in whether Esperanto has morphed naturally, without the involvement of a committee.  All things considered, my vote stands.