# Updating FAQ for conlang questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The community discussed [Should we include Conlangs in our scope?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/should-we-include-conlangs-in-our-scope) a few years ago. It was decided then that conlang questions will remain on-topic at Linguistics SE.

**However, [Constructed Languages SE](https://conlang.stackexchange.com) is now a thriving community for asking questions on conlangs; there is generally not much point in entertaining such questions here.**

We will have to update the FAQ to reflect the change. I'm open to the issue that there *could* be some kinds of questions on conlangs that are of interest to linguists in general. To help with updating the FAQ, could you please let me know what kinds of conlang questions, if any, could be of interest to linguists or the Linguistics SE community, rather than the Constructed Languages SE community?

By default, I'll update the FAQ to indicate all conlang questions as off-topic at Linguistics SE.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that anything about creating conlangs should definitely be sent to the Conlangs site.

Descriptive questions analysing conlangs with speech communities (like Esperanto, Klingon) as we'd analyse any natural language should probably still be allowed here.

Questions that fall in between should probably be sent to the other site.